# Prove that $|^{\{0,1\}}A| =_c |A \times A|$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that $|^{\{0,1\}}A| =_c |A \times A|$.  Here we're defining $^{\{0,1\}}A$ as all the functions $f:\{0,1\} \to A$, and $=_c$ as having the same cardinality.

**Attempt**: I know we are to construct a bijection $g:^{\{0,1\}}A \to A \times A$.  I tried to define $g$ by $g(x)=(f(x),f(x-1))$, but I don't think that makes any sense because the input needs to be the functions f.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your g is invalid, for instance because what does it even mean to subtract one from element of arbitrary set?

Comment: Try $g(f) = (f(0),f(1))$ where $f$ is a function from {0,1} to $A$.

Comment: @enedil f, as stated, is a function from {0,1} to A.  i.e. it's (f(1),f(0)) or (f(0),f(1)).

Comment: @Ned Is this a bijection though?  How do you know?

Comment: Show that it is injective and surjective. It's straightforward, no tricks required. For example, for subjectivity, let $(a,b)$ be an arbitrary element of $A x A$. Find an $f$ for which $g(f)=(a,b)$. Etc.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Phi: ^{\{0,1\}}\!\!{A} \to A \times A$ by $\Phi(f)=(f(0),f(1))$. This is well-defined, as $f \in ^{\{0,1\}}\!\!{A}$ and thus a function $f:\{0,1\} \to A$, which makes $f(0), f(1) \in A$ well-defined points.

This $\Phi$ is a bijection: suppose $\Phi(f) = \Phi(f')$ for $f,f':\{0,1\} \to A$.
This means that $(f(0),f(1)) = (f'(0), f'(1))$ and so (by equality of Cartesian pairs) $f(0)=f'(0)$ and $f(1) = f'(1)$. So $f$ and $f'$ agree on the domain $\{0,1\}$ and thus by definition are equal functions, or $f=f'$, and $\Phi$ is thus shown to be injective.

If $(a,a') \in A \times A$ is arbitrary, we know that $a,a' \in A$ and we can define $f: \{0,1\} \to A$ by $f(0)=a, f(1)=a'$ (or $f=\{(0,a), (1,a')\}$ if you prefer) and then by definition of $\Phi$: $\Phi(f)=(a,a')$ so that $\Phi$ is onto.

$\Phi$ witnesses that $|^{\{0,1\}}\!\!{A}|=_c |A \times A|$.